# Does Umbraco have the ability for Umbraco administrators to login, and write regular emails that could be sent out to subscribed users daily/weekly?

Tags: asp.net, cron, content-management-system, smtp, umbraco

Here is an outline of the technologies were are using for our project at work :

- ASP.NET MVC 4
- Visual Studio 2012 and Visual Studio 2010
- Entity Framework Version 4
- Umbraco 6.1.6

We want the application to **send out daily/weekly emails to subscribed users**.  Basically, I believe we need to setup cron jobs.

Does Umbraco have the ability for Umbraco administrators to login, and write regular emails that could be sent out to subscribed users daily/weekly?

Answer (score 2):

There is a [scheduler in Umbraco](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/install-and-setup/scheduled-tasks), which you can use to schedule jobs.  Pay attention, if IIS is stopped due to inactivity the scheduler won't be able to run.  Second remark, if sending out thousands of e-mails, make sure you don't stall your website.
Using the System.Net.Smtp client from asp.net you would be able to write it yourself fairly easy.

Or you might be interested in a commercial package: http://www.newsletterstudio.org/

Answer (score 1):

You can do all this in Umbraco, but I would consider integrating an external mailshot platform into Umbraco to make the system more solid.

You can use any of the big mailshot packages to do this job; I've integrated DotMailer with Umbraco - but MailChimp, CampaignMonitor, Pure360 and many more offer the same facilities.

In the mailshot package you:

- store the email addresses
- define the email template
- reserve placeholders for custom fields to contain content managed images, copy etc
- schedule the mailshot

In Umbraco you:

- content manage the copy & images etc
- trigger a push of the copy & images to the mailshot package custom fields

In essence you content manage in Umbraco the aspects of your mailshot that change each week.  When you have finished with the weeks content then push the copy & images to the mailshot tool using the API of the mailshot tool (probably in a custom Umbraco section).  When the scheduled time arrives the mailshot package will merge together the template & custom fields and send the emails.  You can also trigger an instant send directly from Umbraco via the API (in DotMailer I seem to remember there is a SendCampaign() method)

Every big mailshot package has 'custom fields' against every email address that you can drop Umbraco content into via the API.  So you can transfer references to images, copy, headings etc to the mailshot tool that you have content managed in Umbraco.  You can also personalize this content so that different people in the mailing list see different images, copy or whatever.  With images you need to ensure that folder permissions will allow them to be picked up by an mail client - eg the /images/mailshot folder of your website.

As the mailshot tool will handle the scheduling, sending & monitoring of the mailing each week it will not require you to worry about your own server cron jobs.